# Kivy: button on_press switch to next tab using kivy builder

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I'm new to python and kivy so please be gentle :)

I have 3 tabs and want the app to show the next tab when I press button1 and button2, and to shutdown itself when button3 is pressed. I would like to use kivy builder to do this, if possible.

Please help :/

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.lang import Builder

class Root(TabbedPanel):
    pass

Builder.load_string('''
<Root>
    do_default_tab: False
    size_hint: 1, 1
    post_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'y': .5}
    do_default_tab: False
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Step 1'
        FloatLayout:
            Button:
                id: button1
                size_hint: .10, .10
                pos: 1350, 40
                orientation: 'vertical'
                text: 'Next!'
                on_press: print("go to next step") #need help
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Step 2'
        FloatLayout:
            Button:
                id: button2
                size_hint: .10, .10
                pos: 1350, 40
                orientation: 'vertical'
                text: 'Next!'
                on_press: print("go to next step") #need help
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Step 3'
        FloatLayout:
            Button:
                id: button3
                size_hint: .10, .10
                pos: 1350, 40
                orientation: 'vertical'
                text: 'The End.'
                on_press: print("exiting") #need help
''')

class TabbedPanelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Root()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TabbedPanelApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TabbedPanel.switch_to](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.tabbedpanel.html#kivy.uix.tabbedpanel.TabbedPanel.switch_to) seems pretty straightforward to me. Just use it like this in those three `on_press`:

```
root.switch_to(root.tab_list[1])
root.switch_to(root.tab_list[0])
root.switch_to(root.tab_list[2])
```

`tab_list` is in "reversed" order - the last added `TabbedPanelItem` is the first item in list.